# PostgreSQL filter table with LIKE on another table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables:

Wikpedia:

```
Id, Title
1,USA
2,USA Army
3,Canada
4,Britain
```

Events:

```
Id, Key1, Key2, Key3
1, US, USA, United States
2, Britain, Britain, Brit
3, US, US, US
4, Mex, Mexico, MX
```

I want to find all entries of titles from Wikipedia table that match either of the three keywords Key1, or Key2 or Key3

Basically, on the frontend side, a user will select a country, according to that I plan to filter the table Events. The keys columns in events table may not necessarily contain country names, it could be something else related to the country, like New York

Thus I have now 3 Keywords, USA, United States, New York, I want to find all relevant titles in Wikipedia from these filtered keywords

Is there are a way to filter data from another table without join?

Query intended [A user input of country and period], however it gives same results for any country in {0} (With help from "a_horse_with_no_name")

```
select title, count 
from wiki w 
where exists ( select * 
        from eventsxgeog exg 
        where actor1name = '{0}' or actor1geo_fullname = '{0}' 
        or actor2name = '{0}' or actor2geo_fullname= '{0}'
        or actiongeo_fullname= '{0}' and extract(year from dateadded) = {1} 
        and w.title in (exg.actor1name, exg.actor2name, exg.actor1geo_fullname, 
                    exg.actor2geo_fullname, exg.actiongeo_fullname)) 
and year = {1} order by count desc limit 5;
```

Comment: You can do an EXISTS, but what's wrong with a join?

Comment: You consider 'USA Army' a match for event 1. Probably, because it starts with 'US' and with 'USA'. Is your rule hence that the title must start with the key? Or must it contain the key? Please tell us the exact rule you want applied here. Be aware that 'DE' is the country code for Germany, but 'DENMARK' starts with 'DE'.

Comment: Hi Thorsten, I am looking for any kind of match, not just begins with. Jarlh, I am avoiding join because I am working on 3 TB sized data, so join would slow me down

Comment: A join is not slower per se, but with multiple events you'd get the wikipedia rows multifold and this would be slower. Use an exists clause as suggested by jarlh and a_horse_with_no_name. Do you know how to write the LIKE conditions?

Comment: I know how to write LIKE, but unfortunately I can't get this working, I receive same results for any user input

Comment: Compare the results of `select 1=1 or 1=2 and 1=3;` and `select (1=1 or 1=2) and 1=3;` It could to describe your problem. Use parentheses in complex conditions even if you thing that it is obvious.

Comment: I see. But after I have parentheses, I receive empty arrays as results

Comment: @gammauniversity I think it is because you are using `in` instead of bunch of `like` or `like any`

Comment: I tried using LIKE but I still have the same situation, same results for different parameters.

Comment: Debug your query (remove conditions one by one to get know which is causing the issue). As you know we are have not your actual data here so we are can't do it for you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an EXISTS condition:

```
select wp.*
from wikipedia_table wp
where exists (select * 
              from events e
              where wp.title in (e.key1, e.key2, e.key3));
```

If you want a partial match, you can use a LIKE condition:

```
select wp.*
from wikipedia_table wp
where exists (select * 
              from events e
              where wp.title ilike '%'||e.key1||'%'
                 or wp.title ilike '%'||e.key2||'%'
                 or wp.title ilike '%'||e.key3||'%');
```

Or a bit more compact using `ilike any (..)`:

```
select wp.*
from wikipedia_table wp
where exists (select * 
              from events e
              where wp.title ilike any (array['%'||e.key1||'%', '%'||e.key2||'%', '%'||e.key3||'%'));
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the update, I had to update my question to clearly express what I am intending, can you please retake a look?

Comment: Weirdly I have same results for any user input, don't know why!